# Register a Control assembly on web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, ckeditor, .net-assembly

I'm using CKEditor in my project, but I'm trying to get it to work without the need to declare the assembly in every page that I'm using it.

The assembly that I declare is this one:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>
```

Following the instructions on [this website](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/26/tip-trick-how-to-register-user-controls-and-custom-controls-in-web-config.aspx), I made the following changes in my web.config

```
  <system.web>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="CKEditor" assembly="CKEditor.NET"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
```

But I keep getting this error

> **Parser Error Message:** Invalid or missing attributes found in the tagPrefix entry. For user control, you must also specify 'tagName' and
>   'src'. For custom control, you must also specify 'namespace', and
>   optionally 'assembly'

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong. Maybe is a silly thing, not sure.

Comment: Note, if I declare this assembly, that I show in my question, In the page that I need. the CKEditor works just fine.

Comment: _For custom control, you must also specify 'namespace', and optionally 'assembly'_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the namespace.

> ... For custom control, you must also specify 'namespace', and
>   optionally 'assembly'.

```
  <system.web>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="CKEditor" assembly="CKEditor.NET" namespace="CKEditor"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
```

Assuming the namespace is CKEditor, of course.

Comment: OMG! I need to shoot myself here >.<

Comment: I swear I didn't saw that about namespace (and I read that error a couple of times) =X

Comment: It happens to all of us now and then :)

Comment: Code blindness, happens to us all!

Answer (score 1):

Example

```
  <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

Note in comparison to that you are missing the namespace, as well as a version (if applicable) as your error states you need to specify a namespace as well as an assembly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to register it in Web.Config. Follow instruction from official site:

[CKEditor Documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/)

Here's a video in the setup of CKEditor:

[How to install CK Editor (FCK Editor) on your website](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SU6YWME914A)

The easiest way to install this is to use [**Nuget**](http://nuget.org/packages/CKEditor).